# Service principal privileges for app registration creation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, service-principal

I'm using service principal as login item for azure cli. The role of this service principal is "owner".

I'm trying to run:

```
az ad app list
```

and

```
 az ad app create --display-name "Test application 2"
```

and getting error:

> Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the
>   application. For how to configure, please refer
>   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal'.
>   Original error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

What role should I assign to this service principal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service principal is missing permissions related to reading and writing applications in Azure AD.

1. Go to your Azure AD, "Registered applications"
2. Find your service principal (may need to look at all applications instead of just my)
3. Add required permissions as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Once you've selected the right permissions and done. Please click on "Grant Permissions" because these permissions need Admin consent.

[image]

Comment: @Dzior you're welcome. Glad to know it worked out :)